# Visual C# Trying to display values in Label

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get certain numeric values to display in a label called "lblOutput" in Visual C#.

However, every time I hit the button to display the values the program freezes.

Am I using the right syntax to display the values out to the label?

Included is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TableOfSquaresGUI 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int MAX = 20;
            double number = 1;
            double numberSquared;

            while (number <= MAX)
            {
                numberSquared = Math.Pow(number, 4);
                lblOutput.Text = String.Format("{0} is there entered number 
and the value squared is {1}", number, numberSquared);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the `number` will always be less than `MAX`, so it's going in to endless loop. Hence your program freezes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `number` will always be less than `MAX`, so it's going in to endless loop. Hence your program freezes

Change like this:

```
while (number <= MAX)
{
    numberSquared = Math.Pow(number, 4);
    lblOutput.Text = String.Format("{0} is there entered number and the value squared is {1}", number, numberSquared);
    number++; //add this line
}
```

**EDIT: Added code for new question in comment:**
Option 1:

```
lblOutput.Text += String.Format("{0} is there entered number and the value squared is {1}", number, numberSquared);
```

Option 2 (Recommended):

```
richTextBox.AppendText(String.Format("{0} is there entered number and the value squared is {1}", number, numberSquared) + "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it is just showing me one value.  Is there a way I can get it to show me the values of 1 - 20 squared?

Comment: You need to keep appending the text to the `lblOutput.Text`. Another better option would be to use RichTextBox instead of label. Then use `RichTextBox1.AppendText(String.Format(....) + "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

> Try to write « ToString() »  for your int variables.

And you can replace « String.Format » per a **$**.

### Example

```
lblOutput.Text = $"{number.ToString()} is there entered number 
and the value squared is {numberSquared.ToString()}");
```